# Dynamic content and re-render jquery

Tags: jquery

So, following is code:

```
jQuery('.rhm_add_button').click(function(e) {               
            if(!isMobile) {
                jQuery('.rhm_add_button').featherlight({
                    targetAttr: 'data-add',
                    namespace: 'rhlight_add',
                    root: 'footer'                      
                });                     
            }
        })
```

There is a textfield (`mdl-textfield`) which the featherlight calls it dynamically and mdl does not work.

I did some research and looks like I need to use "componentHandler.upgradeDom();" but I am not sure how.

Can someone show me an example?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post enough code to reproduce the issue? You can create a plunker.